# ¿Cómo puedo hacer esta consulta SQL con JPA?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

Lo que deseo es hacer una consulta que me arroje las últimas 10 registros por orden decreciente de fecha de creación.
Entonces mi consulta SQL sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM turibari.news_item ORDER BY create_date desc limit 10;
```

Cuando intento hacer lo mismo pero con JPA, de esta manera:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT n FROM NewsItem n ORDER BY n.createDate desc limit ?1;")
List<NewsItem> listNews(int limit);
```

, al parecer no reconoce el limit, y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
JDBC exception executing SQL [select n1_0.id_news_item, n1_0.content, n1_0.create_date, n1_0.title from news_item as n1_0 order by n1_0.create_date desc fetch first ? rows only]; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select n1_0.id_news_item, n1_0.content, n1_0.create_date, n1_0.title from news_item as n1_0 order by n1_0.create_date desc fetch first ? rows only]
```

Alguien sabe como hacer bien esta consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar interrogación o dos puntos, solo tienes que seguir el formato en los siguientes ejemplos.

Puedes hacerlo de dos modos:

**Query nativa:**

Añade la propiedad de query nativa en la notacion de @Query : **nativeQuery = true**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT n FROM NewsItem n ORDER BY n.createDate desc limit ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<NewsItem> listNews(int limit);
```

Quité el punto y coma, y si no me equivoco creo que tienes que poner el limit asi:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT n FROM NewsItem n ORDER BY n.createDate desc limit = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Prueba ambos y nos dices.

**Query no nativa:**

```
@Query(value = "FROM NewsItem n ORDER BY n.createDate desc limit = :limit")
List<NewsItem> findByCreateDate(int limit);
```

Personalmente me gusta mas usar querys nativas porque así puedes copiarla y ejecutarla directamente en base de datos y ver que te trae.

Las querys no nativas te permiten hacer consultas a bases de datos sin tener que escribirlas. Y te permite hacer joins y cualquier otro tipo de consulta simplemente escribiendo bien las palabras en el propio nombre de la funcion.
Ejemplo:

```
    Optional<OrderProcessor> findById(long id);
```